# sympy lambdify add two functions

Tags: python, sympy, python-3.6, lambdify

I have two functions created with sympy's lamdify

```
a = sympy.lambdify((x, y), K / (2 * math.pi) * sympy.cos(theta) / r)
b = sympy.lambdify((x, y), -G / (2 * math.pi) * theta)
```

How can I create a new function that is the addition of these two functions?

I tried `c = a + b` but I got

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = lambda x, y: a(x, y) + b(x,y)
```

would work. This is not SymPy specific; just combining two Python functions into third.

But it's more logical to add the expressions before converting to a lambda. For example:

```
var('x y')
expr1 = x + y
a = lambdify((x, y), expr1)
expr2 = x/y
b = lambdify((x, y), expr2)
c = lambdify((x, y), expr1 + expr2)
```

Side remark: I would replace `math.pi` in your function by `sympy.pi`, because `math.pi` is just a floating-point number, while `sympy.pi` is a SymPy object that is recognized as mathematical constant pi.